# Why Phoenix doesn't use Plug to start the server?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

liveforeverx on irc has answered my original question and I have modified this question as a followup.

Phoenix depends on Plug for many of its function. However, when it comes to starting cowboy server, why doesn't Phoenix start it using Plug's api in Phoenix.Endpoint.CowboyHandler.start_link? Why does start_link on ranch_listener_sup is called instead?

Is it because of any limitation of Plug or is it because Phoenix started this way much before Plug's api got matured?

**My Original Question:**

How/where does Phoenix start cowboy?

Reading the Plug docs, I see that to start a server, one has to call

```
Plug.Adapters.Cowboy.http/3
```

However, grepping through my phoenix app and the phoenix source code, I do not see any instance of call to `Plug.Adapters.Cowboy.http/3`. How/where does Phoenix start cowboy?

Comment: Seems from my point of view, because of integration with [websocket stuff](https://github.com/phoenixframework/phoenix/blob/master/lib/phoenix/endpoint/cowboy_handler.ex#L50-L59).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Two reasons:

1. To support websockets
2. Because Phoenix starts the server inside your application supervision tree instead of running your app inside Cowboy